# Beamer presentation fails to compile after TeX Live upgrade

Tags: beamer, texlive, ubuntu

After an upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) to 13.04 (Raring), pdfLaTeX fails to compile a simple presentation using Beamer.  Besides Beamer, the only package I am explicitly using is `minted`, for syntax-highlighting purposes.  This is the header of my my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,utf8]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{minted}
```

The invocation of `pdflatex -shell-escape doc.tex` fails with the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 406, version
           `2010/12/07' of package ltxcmds,
           but only version
           `2010/03/09 v1.4 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)'
           is available.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.542 \ltx@newglobalif
                  \ifGPT@pagecolor
```

Any idea on what might have changed between the different TeX Live versions that could have produced this error?  And more importantly, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check you don't have old versions of `ltxcmds.sty` around. What's the line in the `.log` file when `ltxcmds.sty` is loaded?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @egreg: Indeed, there was a stale `.texmf-var` directory on my home.  After I removed it, the compilation completed fine.  Problem solved -- thanks!

Comment: @JonSmark If you don't mind, I'll propose to close this question as too localized. Or you can try to make it more general, like "How can I debug an error such as `You have requested...`"?

Comment: Flagged it. If you _do_ edit the question to make it more general, please add the result of the above discussion as an answer. Then wait for better/more complete anwers truddling by...