# Beamer doesn't compile on windows using minted

Tags: beamer, errors, miktex, minted

Have the same problem than him:
[Beamer presentation fails to compile after TeX Live upgrade](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111354/beamer-presentation-fails-to-compile-after-tex-live-upgrade)

I'm on windows using miktex (texworks), compiling with --shell-escape. I have the same message:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 406, version
           `2010/12/07' of package ltxcmds,
           but only version
           `2010/03/09 v1.4 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)'
           is available.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.542 \ltx@newglobalif
                  \ifGPT@pagecolor
?
```

I think I need the version of the 2010/12/07 but I can't find it.
Does anybody have the solution ?

Edit 28/11: I tried changing the source (pdftex) and patching by myself, but didn't succeed.

Edit 29/11: Here is the log Joseph, http://pastebin.com/ELiHYKHR.
I just wanted to make you remember what is written in minted documentation: "Windows support is sketchy / untested at the moment. There are two complications: installation and usage."
But I'd really like to make it work, and write a tutorial about it.

Edit 29/11 13h45: I removed the sty, I got this:

```
C:\Users\Minipada\Desktop\Cours LaTeX\Presentation>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>presentation_1.aex 
C:\Users\Minipada\Desktop\Cours LaTeX\Presentation>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>presentation_1.aex 
C:\Users\Minipada\Desktop\Cours LaTeX\Presentation>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>presentation_1.aex 
file deleted
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package. See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.80 \usepackage
            [utf8]{inputenc} % Allows accents
?
```

I don't have this when I keep .sty files. Strange ...

Comment: And the solution in the comments to that question does not help?

Comment: Nope, can't solve this ...

Comment: Can you make your log available somewhere? Almost certainly you have an outdated file 'locally' installed.

Comment: Your problem is likely that you have some files in a 'local' folder (for example `C:\Users\Minipada\Desktop\Cours LaTeX\Presentation\infwarerr.sty`). I suspect these are old, and thus causing the problem. Note that these are nothing to do with `minted` (which works fine on Windows once you install Python, _etc._). Try moving the 'local' `.sty` files away from the folder with the presentation.

Comment: Still nothing ?

Comment: @DavidBensoussan Without Pygmentize, which requires a full Python installation on your system, you can't use `minted`.

Comment: Python was installed

Comment: @DavidBensoussan: Show some reaction to what Joseph Wright has written …